# How can I search facebook for a hashtag using the .net FacebookSDK?

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm trying to figure out how to use the FacebookSDK for .net to search Facebook for posts with a #hash tag? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

dynamic facebookFeed = facebookClient.Get("/search?q=" + keyWord + "&type=post");